# Resolvent estimate of hyperbolic Laplacian

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, microlocal-analysis

Consider the Laplacian $-\Delta$ on the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$. For $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus [0, \infty)$, do we have resolvent estimates of the form
 $$\Vert (-\Delta - \lambda I)^{-1}\Vert \leq \frac{C}{|\text{Im}(\lambda)|}$$
which parallel the corresponding estimates from the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$? A reference would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know enough about $\mathbb{H}^{n}$, but I do know that $\|(A-\lambda)^{-1}\| \le 1/|\mbox{Im}\lambda|$ for all selfadjoint operators $A$ on a Hilbert space. This follows from $\mbox{Im}((A-\lambda I)f,f)=\mbox{Im}\lambda \|f\|^{2}$.